# KVM Windows 7 graphics performance using remote desktop

Tags: kvm-virtualization, remote-desktop

I'm have a Windows 7 installed as a KVM guest on Ubuntu Server 14.04 (headless server). Virtio driver is installed (for system disk). Graphics performance is bad due to lack of graphics driver - there is only a "standard VGA adapter" in a Device manager.

Does any "Guest additions" exist for KVM and Windows (7/8)? Is it possible to use Aero on KVM? I want to use RDP, but if VNC is good enough to support graphic effects, I don't care.

VM create command:

> virt-install --connect qemu:///system --name win7develop --ram 8192
>   --vcpus 2 --disk path=sysdisk.qcow2,format=qcow2,bus=virtio,cache=none --boot hd --network=bridge:br0,model=e1000 --vnc --vncport=5900 --video=qxl --os-type=windows --os-variant=win7 --noautoconsole --accelerate --noapic --arch x86_64

Host CPU is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1246 v3 @ 3.50GHz (integrated graphics).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, set the virtual machine's video driver to SPICE and then install the SPICE guest tools in the Windows guest.